# Stiffness of a leg link

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to simulate a [rhex-robot](http://kodlab.seas.upenn.edu/Kod/Xrhextech) that has this kind of legs:

My question is how can I set (in the urdf file) the stiffnes of the leg_link.  I know how to set kp and kd (contact stiffness and damping parametres), but they are referred to a JOINT, and I want set the stiffness of a specific LINK. I've been able to simulate the robot, but the legs behave as if they were rigid. I would like them to behave like this:

[image: image description]

(when the leg touches the ground, the circunference "deforms")

How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9247/stiffness-of-a-leg-link/) by [ROS_GAZEBO_USER](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1326/ros_gazebo_user/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-09-01**:
I know that with SDF you can set kp and kd for a [link](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision#ode_kp) too. Maybe you can check this [world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f18cbd0511191beed6f602a5fec2049e717c65ad/test/worlds/spring_damper_test.world#spring_damper_test.world-644) as an example, more specifically `model_5_soft_contact`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We can't simulate a flexible link. You can approximate this leg using a series of links connected by hinge joints.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0